# print command not found

Tags: shell, ksh

From the korn shell, I keep getting print command not found. When I run print from the shell, it says the same thing. How would I go about fixing this? printf works fine, but for some reason print is not.

This is redhat 5.5 and the ksh is 3.2.25-release.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the print command does what you think it does? On my Debian system, it's a symlink to run-mailcap from the mime-support package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could we have a little more information, please?  "print" is a shell built-in function for ksh, and it should always be there.  Here's some information from my own redhat system:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat\-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.3 (Santiago)

$ /bin/ksh --version
version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21

$ whence -v print
print is a shell builtin
```

You might also check to see that you have no aliases named "print".  I don't have any executables named "print" in /usr/bin, or /bin, etc.  You might check whether that is also true for you.  Start a new instance of the shell (type "/bin/ksh") and then say

```
PATH= whence -v print
```

Comment: it is "GNU bash, version 3.2.5(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)", I just noticed it says GNU bash. It looks like some how it created a symlink to that. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such version of ksh. This is the version of bash on RHEL 5.5, however, so it looks like you're using bash. Are you looking for the ksh builtin? Use `echo` or `printf` instead. Or run ksh (which might not be installed, bash is the de facto standard shell on non-embedded Linux installations).

Here's a guide to translation `print` options to POSIX-compliant `printf`.

- No option or `-e`: `printf '%b\n'`
- With `-n`: omit `\n` from the format (`printf %b` or `printf %s`)
- `-p`: if you need coprocesses, you need ksh
- With `-r` or `-R`: `printf '%s\n'`
- `-s`: redirect to the desired output file explicitly, with `>>` for appending
- `-u`: use redirection, e.g. `printf … >&3`